# How to get this type of slide in beamer[content with caption]?

Tags: beamer, presentations

How can I get this type of style with beamer?:

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `columns` as explained here: https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/14/beamer-series-pt2.html (where the image is from, in fact). Keep in mind that anything can be put into a column: it doesn't have to be just text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Example showing solution

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{From Beamer Manual -- topic columns}

    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          \tiny  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet scelerisque sem. Integer aliquam turpis id felis dictum, sed placerat dolor sodales. Proin condimentum purus non finibus auctor. In arcu nisi, feugiat nec sem nec, auctor iaculis diam. Donec varius est volutpat sagittis fermentum. Maecenas sagittis libero enim, varius consequat lorem luctus vel. Sed quis turpis quis ex venenatis ultrices non a lacus. Ut quis pellentesque velit. Donec ultrices iaculis tortor vel lacinia. In. 
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{lionslide}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Yielding
[image]